# File name not displayed properly

Tags: android, image-uploading

I want to upload an image to web server.For that i have written code,but when ever i upload the file to web server instead of file name i am getting the image path.

COde

```
protected String sendFile(final Context context, final String url, final String params, String fileName, final File f) {
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        int bytesRead = 0, bytesAvailable = 0, bufferSize;
        int maxBufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer;
        String serverResponseMessage = null;
        String uploaded_file = fileName;


        URL url1 = null;
        try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
            url1 = new URL(url + "?" + params);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
            fileName = String.valueOf(f);
            //connection.setRequestProperty ("uploaded_file", "sample");
            dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"hello" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);


            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            dos.close();

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            StringBuffer b;
            int ch;
            InputStream is;
            is = connection.getInputStream();
            // retrieve the response from server

            b = new StringBuffer();
            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                b.append((char) ch);
            }
            String response = b.toString();
            Log.e("Response", "" + response);


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error message", "" + e);
        }
        return serverResponseMessage;
    }

    protected File saveFile(Context context, int value, String name) {

        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pocketDocs/Camera/Gallery/Others");
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }

        if (value == 0) {
            f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pocketDocs/Gallery", name);
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return f;
    }
}
```

When i use

```
fileName = String.valueOf(f);
  dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"hello" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
```

at server side i am getting the file name as the path of image.

And when i don't use

```
fileName = String.valueOf(f);
```

i am gettin the proper file name but i am not getting the extension of the image.

Now how can i solve this problem because the peoblem is in this line

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"hello" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
```

Comment: Why don't you use f.getName() instead?

Comment: where should i use that

Comment: fileName = f.getName();

Comment: Did you get it right?

Comment: @joao2fast4u please can you write you ans in a post so that i can tick mark it

Comment: Answer posted. Thank you

Comment: @joao2fast4u sir i wannna upload a file to webserver, so for that i am using Ion library.But sir i am getting error in that,please can you help me out??

Comment: Are you talking about this post or is it another question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58342/discussion-between-user3844417-and-joao2fast4u).

Comment: I cant sir at my office its blocked :( Sir i have added you on google plus can we chat on hangout????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using `String.valueOf()` in a file to get its name, it was returning an empty String, so it was not working. 
Instead, you have to get the file name using `file.getName()`.